# Our Guests have arrived/arrived.They are sitting in the garden

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

> Our Guest _____________.They are sitting in the garden.

options:

a)arrived b)have arrived c)had arrived.

MyApproach:

a)I am confused between a)arrived  b)have arrived

> Which Tense usage is used in this Example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(B) is better.

(C) is not correct, because the "are sitting" tells us the conversation is about what is happening now, not what was happening in the past. The time sapn should span from a point in the past up to now.

(A) is possible but not natural. Usually we prefer present perfect over past simple to say a recent change of things.

Comment: (A) might be used if the arrival was very memorable in its own right. If, for instance, the guests arrived at a party by helicopter or parachute, (A) could be used as a form of understatement. The speaker's tone of voice would probably make it plain that there was something peculiar going on.

Answer (score 2):

(a) Our guests have arrived. They are sitting in the garden.

(b) Our guests arrived. They are sitting in the garden.

(c) Our guests had arrived. They are sitting in the garden.

In BE, you always use the present perfect for recent actions, so the  sentence (a) is the correct one.

In AE, though the present perfect is preferable for recent actions, you can also use the past simple.  So the sentences (a) & (b) are correct in AE.

As for the sentence (c), it's incorrect grammatically. The past perfect is used to refer to an action that happened before another action in the past such as "Our guests had arrived. They were sitting in the garden".

Comment: In my exams In India Which to prefer?:P

Comment: We normally follow BE in India ,& Pakistan. So your answer should be in BE  i.e. .......have arrived.